# Deserialize JSON to Java enum

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following enumeration in Java on Android and I would like to be able to deserialize an integer in an incoming JSON string/object into this Enum type. I have been getting hits on Jackson and GSON but nothing on the JSON.org package, which I am using.

Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to alter the JSON decoder? Thanks.

```
public enum ValueEnum {

    ONE(1),
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3);

    private int value;

    private ValueEnum(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ValueEnum.values()` will return you array of ValueEnum[] then you can iterate over array and check for `Value`

```
public static ValueEnum valueOf(int value) {
        ValueEnum[] valueEnums = ValueEnum.values();
        for (ValueEnum valueEnum : valueEnums) {
            if (valueEnum.getValue() == value)
            {
                return valueEnum;
            }
        }
        return DEFAULT;
    }
```