# How to convert integer in request parameter to enum for a field of enum type without using @JsonCreator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, enums

in our project we define enumerations like below

```
public enum GenderEnum implements IEnum{
  MALE(1),
  FEMALE(2);

  private Integer code;

  GenderEnum(int code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public static GenderEnum getByCode(int code) {
    for (GenderEnum genderEnum : values()) {
        if (genderEnum.code == code) {
            return genderEnum;
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

we want to use these enumerations in classes used for parameters, like

```
public class Param{
  String id;
  GenderEnum gender;
}
```

we have controllers like

```
@RestController
class MyController{
  @PostMapping('/alink')
  ResponseBean doSomething(@RequestBody Param param){
      ...
  }
}
```

for the above case, when the request body is

```
{"id":"L323", "gender":1}
```

we hope `1` can be converted into the enum `MALE`

One solution is to add `@JsonCreator` over `getByCode(int code)`。But in our existing project, the repository layer converts enum to its String value(`MALE` or `FEMALE`) but not `code` value before inserting them into database. So if we add `@JsonCreator` over `getByCode(int code)`, we will encounter errors when trying to retrieve enums from database.

how can we make mvc/controller convert integer value of the input into enum without affecting the repository layer?

I see a solution as below:

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {  
            registry.addConverterFactory(new EnumConverterFactory());
        }
    }



static class EnumConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<Integer, IEnum> {
    @Override
    public <T extends IEnum> Converter<Integer, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
        if (!targetType.isEnum()) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(targetType + "is not enum");
        }
        return new EnumConverter(targetType);
    }

    private static class EnumConverter<T extends IEnum> implements Converter<Integer, T> {
        private final Class<T> enumType;

        public EnumConverter(Class<T> enumType) {
            this.enumType = enumType;
        }

        @Override
        public T convert(Integer code) {
            for (T t : enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
                if (code.equals(t.getCode())) {
                    return t;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

but this solution doesn't work. When debugging, I notice the resolving of the parameter depends on Jackson's serialization(which converts integer to enum according to the ordinal instead of the code value) and the converter is simply not involved.

so, are there any workaround?

Comment: This URL might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505102/deserialize-java-enum-from-json

Comment: How do you retrieve elements? Can you show the code?
Defining the enum like MALE("MALE") can be used as a work around i think

Comment: @ShamilPuthukkot `"gender":1` this is decided by product manager

Comment: Not convinced by the design however you should be able to register a custome serializer and deserializer for the field: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-serialize-deserialize.html

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can in your controller declare method for custom mapping of specific type parameters:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {

        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(GenderEnum.class,
            new PropertyEditorSupport() {
                @Override
                public void setAsText(String value){                    
                    setValue(GenderEnum.getByCode(Integer.parseInt(value));
                }               
            });     
    }
```